# Wrong date on email notification

Tags: bug, email-notification

[image: image description]

I'm not sure what day I last checked my inbox, but definitely not 17 May 2015. The email was sent to me 4 hours ago.

Comment: Weird, May 18 for me. lol

Comment: you have every error I have? :-o

Comment: Probably, yeah. ;)

Comment: Also, does closing the question make the team not aware of it?

Comment: Nope, they'll still see it just fine. Just to be sure, I placed a bounty on the original report.

Comment: I've seen several cases of old bugs reported again, the new report closed as dupe, then shortly after SE developer appears and fixing the bug.

Comment: Huh, those dates (in your and @Sha's question) are suspiciously close...

Comment: @nicael he's not my sock, if that's what you're implying... ;)

Comment: @Sha lol nope, but that's a mystical date, that's what I mean. Much time passed, still around the same date.

Comment: It's finally fixed! See answer in dupe. :)

Comment: You come to every question to announce this? :-ooo